# Firebase dynamic link handleUniversalLink returns nil dynamicLink after moving code to separate framework

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

Dynamic links just recently stopped working in the dev branch of my iOS app and I cannot find the reason.
handleUniversalLink callback systematically returns nil and when I do a DynamicLinks.performDiagnostics(...), I get the error message:

> ERROR: Specified custom URL scheme is (null) but Info.plist do not
>   contain such scheme in CFBundleURLTypes key

1. I  know that by the time I try to handle dynamic links, the Firebase stack is configured (I can query my Firebase database and retrieve data).
2. I know the Firebase back end of my project works fine because the previous version of my app can still process dynamic links correctly.
3. I did not make any changes to my info.plist of my GoogleService-Info.plist

I obviously messed up something (maybe in the Firebase configuration code) but I cannot figure out what I did that caused Firebase dynamic links to stop working.
Any idea on that ?

Comment: Here is some more information: this happened after I moved my Firebase related code into a separate framework (I need to use the same framework in two apps). If I move this code back inside my main app, then I do not have the problem any more. Also, this is the only one of my 200+ unit tests on that framework that fails after I moved this code into a framework, everything else (realtime database in particular) works like a charm

Comment: Also, just in case, I did setup deepLinkURLScheme explicitely in the firebase options I use to initialize Firebase, but that still gives me the same error.

Comment: Hi! Were you able to figure this one out?

Comment: Nope, I have been working arround this issue since then, but the issue is still there